# Relations and differences between marshall/unmarshal, encoding/decoding, and serialization/deserialization for JSON?

Tags: json, serialization, go, marshalling, json-deserialization

In Go's JSON package, I saw there are `marshal`, `decode` and other functions.

I thought that `decode` is the opposite to `marshal`, but latter realized that I might be wrong.

I think the fundamental question that I have is:

What are the relations and differences between marshall/unmarshal, encoding/decoding, and serialization/deserialization for JSON?

Thanks.

See an example here [Why are json package's Decode and Marshal methods used here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620151/why-are-json-packages-decode-and-marshal-methods-used-here)

Comment: @ Tim, why you haven't picked *the* answer yet? Still unsatisfied?

Answer (score 9):

I would personally say all those terms are synonyms though less so with encoding/decoding. In Go Marshal and Unmarshal happen to be the terms that are used to describe converting json in a string form to an object and vice versa. However in C# these same methods are called serialize and deserialize, as far as I know that terminology isn't in Go at all (at least not in any std lib).

Encoding can be used as an adjective to describe the format in which some data is stored, the most common use is probably character encoding (UTF-8). In Go it's also used as a noun to describe objects that can unmarshal/marshal json. Marshal/Unmarshal are always used as verbs, you take that action on the json.

Encoding is also used in Go to refer to a larger category of packages that deal with the conversion from one encoding to another.

If you told me you were marshalling, marshalling, deserializing or serializing some object or json I would understand exactly what you meant. If you said you were json encoding an object I would ask a clarifying question. If you said the "response is json encoded" I would get what you mean though I would think it's odd that you used those words rather than just saying "the response is json". Hope that is more or less the information you're looking for.

Oh also, just for more clarity

`Unmarshal == deserialize == decode`

`Marshal == serialize == encode`

Comment: Thanks. See an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620151/why-are-json-packages-decode-and-marshal-methods-used-here

Comment: @Tim I'll take a look at that when I get a minute.

Answer (score 3):

In the `encoding/json` package, the [`Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) function and the inverse [`Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unarshal)function return and operate on single fixed bytes slices. They transform single objects to bytes, and vice versa.

There are also the [`Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) and [`Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) types. These contain the [`Encode`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder.Encode) and [`Decode`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode) methods, and they operate on streams of bytes, taking an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) and [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) respectively. They also allow *multiple* objects to be serialized or deserialized with a newline delimiter using those streams.

The underlying mechanisms of Marshal/Unmarshal functions and the Encoder/Decoder types are identical, they both use the same internal `encodeState.marshal` and `decodeState.unmarshal` codepaths. The only real difference is they provide alternative access for various usage patterns.

Comment: Thanks. See an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620151/why-are-json-packages-decode-and-marshal-methods-used-here