# Why are json package's Decode and Marshal methods used here?

Tags: json, go

In the following example from [Web Development with Go by Shiju Varghese](https://books.google.com/books?id=OalPCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR2&dq=web%20application%20in%20go&pg=PA155#v=onepage&q=web%20application%20in%20go&f=false), which is for implementing a HTTP server using a new MongoDB session for each HTTP request:

- Why is `json` package's `Decode` method used in `PostCategory` function?
- Why is `json` package's `Marshal` method used in `GetCategories` function?

At first I thought that `Decode` in `PostCategory` and `Marshal` in `GetCategories` are opposite to each other, but later I found that there is a `Unmarshal` method and maybe a `Encode` one in the `json` package. So I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618339/) earlier.

Here is the program

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)
var session *mgo.Session

type (
    Category struct {
Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
Name string
Description string
    }
    DataStore struct {
session *mgo.Session
    }
)
//Close mgo.Session
func (d *DataStore) Close() {
    d.session.Close()
}
//Returns a collection from the database.
func (d *DataStore) C(name string) *mgo.Collection {
    return d.session.DB("taskdb").C(name)
}
//Create a new DataStore object for each HTTP request
func NewDataStore() *DataStore {
    ds := &DataStore{
session: session.Copy(),
    }
    return ds
}

//Insert a record
func PostCategory(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var category Category
    // Decode the incoming Category json
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&category)
    if err != nil {
panic(err)
    }
    ds := NewDataStore()
    defer ds.Close()
    //Getting the mgo.Collection
    c := ds.C("categories")
    //Insert record
    err = c.Insert(&category)
    if err != nil {
panic(err)
    }
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
}

//Read all records
func GetCategories(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var categories []Category
    ds := NewDataStore()
    defer ds.Close()
    //Getting the mgo.Collection
    c := ds.C("categories")
    iter := c.Find(nil).Iter()
    result := Category{}
    for iter.Next(&result) {
categories = append(categories, result)
    }
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
j, err := json.Marshal(categories)
if err != nil {
panic(err)
    }
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
w.Write(j)
}

func main() {
    var err error
    session, err = mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
panic(err)
    }
    r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/api/categories", GetCategories).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/api/categories", PostCategory).Methods("POST")
    server := &http.Server{
Addr:    ":8080",
Handler: r,
    }
    log.Println("Listening...")
    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the main reason for using a `json.NewDecoder` here is to read directly from response's body (`r.Body`) here, since `NewDecoder` takes an `io.Reader` as an input.

You could have used `json.Unmarshal` but then you'd have to first read response body into a `[]byte` and pass that value to `json.Unmarshal`. `NewDecoder` is more convenient here.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that `Unmarshal` and `Decode` can apply to the same object, and the only difference is that the object should be treated as a byte array for `Unmarshal` while the object should be treated as an `io.Reader` object?

Comment: That is basically the idea. In fact, if you look at `Decode`'s source, you'll see that it also uses `Unmarshal` internally (although defined as a private package member. (https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L67)

Comment: Also, `Decode` is very useful when you have a type implementing the `json.Unmarshaler` interface, as it can be used to decode nested structures. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587157/golang-having-trouble-with-nested-json-unmarshaler

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR —** `Marshal`/`Unmarshal` take and return byte slices, while `Encode`/`Decode` do the same thing, but read the bytes from a stream such as a network connection (readers and writers).

The [`encoding/json`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json) package uses the [`Encoder`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Encoder) and [`Decoder`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder) types to act on *streams* of data, that is, [`io.Reader`](https://godoc.org/io#Reader)'s and [`io.Writer`](https://godoc.org/io#Writer)'s. This means that you can take data directly from a network socket (or an HTTP body in this case which implements `io.Reader`) and transform it to JSON as the bytes come in. Doing it this way, we can go ahead and start processing that JSON as soon as any data is available but before we've received the whole document (on a slow network connection with a big document this could save us a lot of time, and for some streaming protocols with "infinitely sized" document streams this is absolutely necessary!)

`Marshal` and `Unmarshal` however operate on byte slices, which means that you have to have the entirety of the JSON document in memory before you can use them. In your example, the author uses Marshal because they already have a `[]byte` slice so there's no point in constructing a buffer using the byte slice, then making an encoder that uses that buffer, then calling encode: Instead they can just let Marshal do that for them.

In reality, Marshal/Unmarshal are just convenience methods on top of Encoders and Decoders. If we look at the [source for Unmarshal](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go#L85), we see that under the hood it's just constructing an encoder (or the internal representation of an encoder, but trust me, they're the same thing, if you want proof you can look at the [Encode method source](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go#L183) and see that it's also creating an `encodeState`) and then returning the output bytes:

```
func Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    e := &encodeState{}
    err := e.marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return e.Bytes(), nil
}
```